# Is there an error in equilibrio puzzle #45?

Tags: puzzles, equilibrio

Is there an error in puzzle #45 of the game equilibrio? seems like the middle brick on the third line is turned incorrectly. thanks

Comment: Are you speaking of the video game, or board/puzzle game: http://www.amazon.com/FoxMind-5512624-Equilibrio-Game/dp/B000PHQLVK?

Comment: yes, the board game